# Cannot figure out which dependency in pom.xml file causing the deployment on openshift failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat7, openshift

Here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vincent</groupId>
    <artifactId>UploadExample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UploadExample Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <spring-data-jpa.version>1.10.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.2.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.39</mysql.connector.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons FileUpload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thumbnailator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons IO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SLF4J/Logback -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>UploadExample</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the openshift profile will be used when invoking 
                mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the deployments 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>UploadExample</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>UploadExample</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

If I run my application in my local via eclipse, everything works fine. If I upload to openshift, the build was success, but in the logs, I see this:

```
Sep 26, 2016 3:16:53 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/var/lib/openshift/57e48b687628e1e4b4000017/jbossews/work/Catalina/localhost/UploadExample/WEB-INF/lib/el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Sep 26, 2016 3:17:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [javassist/ByteArrayClassPath.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/UploadExample/WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Utility.swallowMethodParameters(Utility.java:796)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Attribute.readAttribute(Attribute.java:171)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FieldOrMethod.<init>(FieldOrMethod.java:57)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Method.<init>(Method.java:71)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:267)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2058)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1934)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1900)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1885)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1317)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)





....
```

I did my research and realized it is dependency problem, but I cannot figure out which one cause that, I hope you can help me, thank you

Comment: Google tells me https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/issues/29

So you could try to remove the dependency. Print the dependency tree to figure out which it is. (mvn dependency:tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it, seems like Openshift doesn't work with newest Hibernate version, I need to downgrade the version from 5.2.0 final to 5.0.11 Final for hibernate, and everything works fine in my local and Openshift. One more important part I counter is make sure your table name in database matches the name in your java dao file(ie, the @Table(name="") part) due to MySQL in Openshift are case sensitive.